# Why does a locked Parallel foreach not deadlock right away?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I noticed a deadlock in my program an relatively quickly found the reason. I was calling a locked getter from a `Parallel.Foreach` loop.
Generally nested locks are no problem, a syncronous `for` loop does indeed not deadlock. But why does the `Parallel.Foreach` loop deadlock and why does it execute more often than two times?

I put an example below.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       new Test().RunTest();
       Console.WriteLine("Test finished");
    }
}

class Test
{
    object lockObject = new object();
    public void RunTest()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            Parallel.For(0, 10, sayHello);
        }
    }
    void sayHello(int i)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

The output varies from run to run. But often it is like

`hello 0
hello 4
hello 5
hello 8
hello 9`

Comment: If you use any locks at all it means there *is* a problem already. Why use locks at all? `Parallel.For/Foreach` partition the data so that each task gets its own data and doesn't need to lock anything

Comment: The rest of the question doesn't make much sense - you are performing 10 iterations in parallel. The order of execution or the number of cores used isnt' guaranteed.

Comment: This example is an excerpt from a very large code base.

Comment: What is your *actual* question anyway? What real problem are you trying to solve? That example looks like an attempt to cause a bug if anything. It doesn't seem to serve any purpose

Comment: `Parallel.For(0, 10, sayHello);` doesn't look like an except

Comment: Change the `Console.WriteLine` to `Console.WriteLine("hello " + i + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);`. Add `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` before each `lock` statement. Notice that when the `ManagedThreadId` changes you will get deadlock. _That isn't a surprise - that is how `lock` is meant to work._

Comment: @linuxrocks if you inherited some bad legacy code you'd have to determine what it does first, then fix it. `Parallel.For` doesn't need locks *UNLESS* the real code tries to access the same shared data as other iterations. Which is what `Parallel.` was built to *avoid*.

Comment: I think it's clear why it deadlocks. As for why it outputs something at all - that's because `Parallel.For` uses current thread to perform part of computation (so that current thread doesn't just wait for result doing nothing). Current thread can enter the lock without problem.

Comment: @linuxrocks was this an attempt to *throttle* Parallel.For` perhaps? Not needed, you can specify the maximun number of concurrent tasks with options. An attempt to aggregate data that ends up eg incrementing the same variable? Not needed, there are Parallel.For overloads that aggregate partial and final results

Comment: @linuxrocks Evk provided the actual answer. Parallel.For uses the current thread *and* threadpool threads to process a lot of data in parallel. The number of threads is calculated at runtime and *increased* if needed. When the runtime sees there are only 10 iterations it may well decide to start with only 2 threads including the original. That original won't have trouble using its own locks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My real legacy code does not say hello but this was the quickest example I could think off :). I also think that `Eck` is right and this makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: @linuxrocks post a *realistic* example then. There should be no locks. There *are* ways to avoid them. Or you shouldn't be using Parallel.For anyway. For example an ActionBlock with a DOP of eg 4 is better for making concurrent HTTP calls from a list of URLs *and* processing the results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lock (lockObject)` in `RunTest` means that only the current thread can pass through any and all subsequent `lock (lockObject)` until the code `Parallel.For(0, 10, sayHello)` completes.

Since you get some output from `sayHello` this means that `Parallel.For` is using the current thread for some of its computation - remember it partitions the number of calls it hands on to each thread based on the cores available on your CPU - and those are hitting the `Console.WriteLine` calls. But the other threads it is using cannot enter the `lock` until the `Parallel.For` completes.

That's why some of the calls succeed.